# Is it possible to use zsh in windows machines?

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Is it possible to use zsh shell in windows along with console 2. If possible how can I install and configure it.

Answer (score 4):

You can if you have Windows 10.  Install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).  You can choose from a variety of free Linux distros from the Windows store.  You can then run `bash` as a program.  Install the `zsh` shell and make you can switch to it or make it the default shell.

As for Console2, I havent used it in ages, but I think you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Yes I am using windows 10. Will check out the Windows sub systems for Linux. And will see how it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) on Windows for compiling things with mingw.
It comes with a lot of additional stuff that can be installed via packages. Such as zsh.

So, if you install the zsh package you can set that as default shell.

However I'd only recommend this over the Windows Subsystem for Linux if:

- You've got no Windows 10
- You need/want the mingw compiler suite